# Is the space of probability density functions Banach?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, banach-spaces

Let $f:{\mathbb R}^m \rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ a probability density function that satisfies $\int_{{\mathbb R}^m} f(x)dx = 1$.

Let $S$ be the space of all density functions on ${\mathbb R}^m$. Is there a metric that makes this space a Banach space?

I suppose that this is classical result (either positive or negative answer), so I mainly need a reference.

Comment: A Banach space is a vector space. How do you define addition and scalar multiplication in your set? You can only then start to think about norms (not metrics) that would make the space a Banach space...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a complete metric space under the $L^{1}$ metric: $d(f,g)=\int|f-g|$. It cannot be a Banach space because it is not a vector space. Proof of the fact that this space is complete: if $f_n$ is  a density function for each $n$ and $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy then there exists $f \in L^{1}$ such that  $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ (because $L^{1}$ is complete). There is a subsequence which converges almost everywhere to $f$. Hence $f \geq 0$ almost everywhere. Of course, $\int f =\lim \int f_n$ so $\int f=1$. Hence $f$ is also a density function proving completeness.

Comment: This is very helpful. Can you provide a general reference for this (just for my further reading)? I will accept the answer soon.

Comment: @SnoopDogg I have included a proof of completeness.

Comment: In other words, the Banach space is $L^1(\mathbb R)$, and probability density functions are a closed subset of it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.